# Access database opening gives 3151 error

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have an Access database which was connected to a msql database on a webserver. The Access database on my desktop synchronised all data with data in the sql database on the webserver.

The sql database on the webserver no longer exists which consequently means that when I open the Access database I get an ODBC error message and I cannot access the data on my desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, presuming that the question is:

`How do I stop Access from giving me this error?`

You can do one of the following

1. Delete the links to the SQL Server tables in your Tables list.
2. Recreate the ODBC connection on your workstation and point it at another database (it could be a dummy database with just the tables you had in the SQL database, but no data)